# Как обновить существующую запись в блоке div?

Tags: javascript

Задача такая:

Из websocket приходит массив с числами

- Если блока div, соответствующего числу, нет на странице, то создать;
- Если такой блок уже есть, то обновить результат, сколько раз это число присутствует в массиве.

Из первого массива, когда страница пустая, получается создать все нужные блоки.

А потом, для новых массивов, надо обновлять или добавлять - как это сделать? Если блок с таким id существует, то обновить только найденное.

Вот начало кода. А как обновлять найденное? Не пойму, подскажите пожалуйста.

```js
//Приходит из сокета..........
 window.ar = ["1","2","2","2"];
//............................


    var arr =  window.ar.sort(
        function(a,b){return (a-b)});
    var check = {};

    for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if( check[arr[i]] ) {
            check[arr[i]]++
        } else {
            check[arr[i]] = 1;
        }
    }

    for( var number in check  ) {
            var win = document.getElementById('win');
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.id = number;
            div.innerHTML = number+'-Найдено раз-'+"<div style='background: green;float: right; width: 20px;text-align: center;'>"+check[number]+"</div>";
            win.appendChild(div);



    }
```

```html
<div id="win"></div>
```

Код в месте с сокетом.

```
websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
   let mess = JSON.parse(event.data);
   for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
       var y = mess;
   }
   if(y.sendnum){
       window.ar = y.sendnum;
       send();
   }
 };
function send() {
var arr = window.ar.sort(
    function(a,b){return (a-b)});
var check = {};

for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    if( check[arr[i]] ) {
        check[arr[i]]++
    } else {
        check[arr[i]] = 1;
    }
}
for( var number in check  ) {
    var win = document.getElementById('win');
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = number;
    div.innerHTML = number+'-Найдено раз-'+"<div style='background: green;float: right; width: 20px;text-align: center;'>"+check[number]+"</div>";
    win.appendChild(div);
}
var e =  document.getElementById('win').childNodes;
console.info(e);
```

}

Comment: мы тоже ничего не поняли, отредактируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос так, что бы можно было разобраться ( пунктуацию и построение предложений )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я полагаю имеется в виду это:

```js
let randomData = () => Array(20).fill(0).map(a => Math.round(Math.random()*5));

draw(randomData())

function draw(d) {

log.textContent = JSON.stringify(d)

// подготавливаем данные, сворачивая их в нечто такое [[0,4],[1:3],...]
d = d.reduce((acc, el) => {
    !acc[el] && (acc[el] = 0);
    acc[el]++;
    return acc;
}, []).map((d,i) => [i, d]).filter(d => d[1]);

// создаем выборку и привязываем к ней данные
let sel = d3.select('body')
    .selectAll('div.element')
    .data(d);

sel.enter() // действия с данными, для которых еще нет узла
   .append('div') // создать div и и добавить на станицу
   .classed('element', true) // навесить на него класс

 // после merge идут действия с вновь появившимися узлами и узлами, которые уже были на странице
   .merge(sel).html(d => d[0] + ": " + d[1])
      
// действия с узлами, которые покидают выборку (тут удаление)
sel.exit().remove();  
}
```

```css
.element {
  font-size:30px;
  border: solid;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-selection/1.2.0/d3-selection.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="draw(randomData())">random</button> data: <span id="log"></span><br><br>
```

PS: Такие манипуляции (`enter` `exit` `update`) - как раз основное предназначение модуля `d3-selection` библиотеки `d3`